# Error opening hard drives on 13.04

Tags: 13.04, hard-drive

I'm getting the following message while opening hard drives on 13.04:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/teja/521C05AA1C0589E5: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/teja/521C05AA1C0589E5"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
    Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
    Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
    The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
    Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
    read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: It seems to be a duplicated ask: http://askubuntu.com/questions/290630/problem-to-enter-in-ntfs-partition or http://askubuntu.com/questions/285809/ubuntu-13-04-dual-boot-problem-unable-to-mount-windows-8-partition

Answer (score 1):

I have had this very issue before. It appears to be a corrupt Windows (NTFS) partition, so if you can, boot into a Windows environment (this could even include WinPE*) and run `chkdsk /f` in a command prompt. (if on Windows Vista/7/8, it must be ran as administrator) If you cannot boot into Windows, see [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/) website on how to repair anything from a corrupt NTFS partition to a broken master boot record from Ubuntu. (if you're looking for how to fix a corrupted NTFS partition, scroll on down to where it says `Fixing A Corrupted Windows NTFS Partition`)

*: `Windows Pre-Installation Environment` This would be booting from a Windows Vista/7/8 install disc or WinPE created disc via alternate methods. (it will take some Googling to find these, one I recommend that's free would be BartPE) If you are on a Windows Vista/7/8 install disc, press SHIFT+F10 after it finishes booting to open a command prompt. (it will have administrator privileges)

Comment: I found the solution to my error.. http://askubuntu.com/a/290637/163946

Comment: For anyone else with this question that wound up here, I posted an improved answer on the topic the OP just stated in the comment before this.